# Ascending numbers every x lines and batch modifying timestamps for .srt file

Tags: unix, batch, notepad++, text-formatting, subtitles

I've been struggling with converting a file in the following format

```
0:01:00.340 --> 0:01:01.380
***subtitle text***

0:01:01.380 --> 0:01:02.390
***subtitle text***
```

into standard .srt format, i.e.:

```
1
0:01:00,320 --> 0:01:01,360
***subtitle text***

2    
0:01:01,360 --> 0:01:02,320
***subtitle text***
```

Cheers in advance!

**EDIT:** removed stuff about my progress prior to LotPing's answer.

Comment: Please, don't crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49929871/372239

Comment: Apologies, first time asking and pressed for time. If cross-posting is against the rules I'll be more than happy to delete one of the two questions

Comment: Other post has been deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite editor [Textpad](http://textpad.com/) can do this, otherwise you'll need a vbscript or Powershell.

[image]

**Edit** The RegEx grew more complex with 3 groups catching the regions around the dots/commas

Search: `^(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.(\d{3}[-> ]+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.(\d{3})`
Replace: `\i\n$1,$2,$3`

What the RegEx does is:

- search for a `h:mm:ss` pattern where `\d` represents a digit and `{1,2}` is a quantifier, meaning one to two occurences. `{2}` Is just two times etc.
- `[-> ]+` is a class of any of the chars inside the `[ ]` the following quantifier `+` means at least one but as many as possible of the class chars.
- `^` anchored at line begin and
- (groups) this
- followed by a literal dot

This is replaced by

- the `\i` increment special to TextPad
- a `\n` newline
- and the grouped `$1` pattern aka time
- and a literal comma.

A valuable source for RegEx is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
and to interactively test out a RegEx or RE use [RegEx101.com](http://regex101.com/)

---

The above RE in [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CPmVOv/1) without the `\i`-feature

Comment: Interesting, so did you manage to change the full-stops to commas as well? I'll copy and paste that into notepad++'s find & replace and see if it helps. 
Also, do you mind quickly explaining what your ^, \d, \i and $1 operators are doing? 
Cheers

Comment: No I didn't but that's no problem to catch with the RE. But I'm sorry npp doesn't support the `\i` increment replacement. I'll update the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the update, you mentioning RegEx has made this a lot easier to research! Copying in your expression on TextPad 8 updates the first h:mm:ss comma, however the second timestamp isn't updated (the one after "-->")

Comment: See the updated RegEx and replacement

Comment: Perfect! Marked as answered, thank you so much. Do you mind explaining the "\d{3}[-> ]+" part of the expression? I understand everything else now, very interesting stuff

Comment: Again edited the answer, you can also vote up ;-)

Comment: Cheers, have done, however my rep is below 15, so it's registered but not publicly shown. I plan on being a lot more active on here though so should show up once I answer some questions I think!

Comment: A valuable source for RegEx is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and to interactively test out a RegEx or RE is [RegEx101.com](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: Bookmarked both :) I also found http://johnbokma.com/textpad/textpad-reference.pdf. If I run into any more problems with this srt file should I ask another question or update this one?

Comment: Ask new questions to get a broader audience. Comments here will get my attention - but I'm not always online.

Answer (score 0):

For a command line solution, I would use [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - a pure script (JScript/batch) regular expression utility that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward without the need of any 3rd party exe file.

The following uses `^` line continuation to avoid scrolling, but it could be put all on one line.

```
jrepl "^(\d+:\d\d:\d\d)\.(\d{3} --> \d+:\d\d:\d\d)\.(\d{3})"^
      "$txt=++n+'\r\n'+$1+','+$2+','+$3" /jq /jbeg "var n=0" /f test.txt /o -
```

Use CALL JREPL if you put the command within a batch script.

Comment: How is this inserting incremental number?

Comment: @Toto - It wasn't - I completely missed that requirement. I've updated the answer to put in the incrementing numbers.